# Flip page horizontal (mirrored page) with AlivePDF

Tags: actionscript-3, air, pdf-generation, alivepdf

I am creating a PDF using AlivePDF in FlashCS5. Everything is workin' fine, but I want to "reflect" the texts or the whole page for print it mirrored without edit the image. Hope some one knows how to. Cheers!

```
myPDF.setFont( regularFont, 160);
myPDF.addText(nombre, 180, 50);
myPDF.setFont( regularFont, 125);
myPDF.addText(tiempo, 20, 50);

var f:FileStream = new FileStream();
file = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("pdf/"+date+"_"+client+".pdf");
f.open( file, FileMode.WRITE);
var bytes:ByteArray = myPDF.save(Method.LOCAL);
f.writeBytes(bytes);
f.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this for any PDF by feeding your un-mirrored PDF plus a little bit of custom PostScript code to Ghostscript. Assuming your page width is 612 pts ("Letter"), one possible command is this:

```
gs \
    -o mirrored.pdf \
    -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
    -c "<</Install {-1 1 scale -612 0 translate}>> setpagedevice" \
    -f un-mirrored.pdf
```

Comment: Hi Kurt. I don't have idea how Ghostscrit works but I asume that it must be installed in the system, right? The problem here is that I want to use only the AIR app and nothing more because I must distribute it and I dont' have the chance to configure the other computers. Tell me if I am wrong about this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, Ghostscript should be installed on the system to make it work. I don't know how to achieve what you want in a pure AIR app.